# Getting error while connecting to database using entity framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have created a database MVCLearn with table general information

I want to display details in view with the help of Id, I used entity framework for data retrieving from database

so if i use id in url i will get the particular details  of that person.

but when i run,  browser is displaying an error this way

[image]

Comment: The error message is self-explanatory - the account you are connecting to the database with doesn't have permissions to do select queries on the db/table

Comment: Seems like an obvious error, the user context in the connection string you are using to connect to the database has no read/select permissions. So what is your question?

Comment: For retrieving data from database do we need to grant permissions for database so that we can use that data in project? If so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you need to grant at least read only permissions to your login which is used to access the database. Here you can find a good tutorial with pictures from Joel Lipman where all of these permissions are described: [Create Read-Only Database User in SQL Server](http://www.joellipman.com/articles/microsoft/sql-server/create-read-only-database-user-in-sql-server.html)

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create/modify a user on the SQL server that has the required permissions on that server. [image]

Use the User Mapping option. Then setup that user for EF

Comment: your Suggestion Worked

Answer (score 0):

As the comments suggested, you need to grant permissions to your user to select data from the table. You can do this for a specific table like this:

```
grant select on dbo.tblEmployee to [YourUser]
```

However, it is more likely that you would want to add your user to a role, for selecting data only, you can use the following:

```
ALTER ROLE db_datareader ADD MEMBER [YourUser]
```

Hope this helps.